# Loading UICollectionViewCell one at a time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

As per this article http://aplus.rs/2014/how-to-animate-in-uicollectionview-items/ I am trying to load a UICollectionViewCell one at a time to animate the cell when it appears. However, when I call the code the loops the cellCount++, it produces this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an
>   existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of
>   items contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus
>   the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

And I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)addCells{

    for (self.cellCount=0; self.cellCount<50; self.cellCount++) {

        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.cellCount inSection:0]]];
        } completion:nil];

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you are updating the data source too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a timer, whose action method adds objects from your data source array to a mutable array that you use to populate your collection view.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.data = @[@"one", @"one", @"one", @"one", @"one", @"one"];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(addCells:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.mutableArray.count;
}


-(void)addCells:(NSTimer *) timer {
    static int counter = 0;
    [self.mutableArray addObject:self.data[counter]];
    counter ++;
    [self.collectionview insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.mutableArray.count -1 inSection:0]]];
    if (self.mutableArray.count == self.data.count) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Makes complete sense as well.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing only works when the datasource is tightly coordinated with the actions you take to add cells.

So *before* you call `insertItemsAtIndexPaths`, make sure that your datasource `numberOfItemsInSection` for section 0 answers your model count.  Your model count needs to match `cellCount` exactly, and your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` needs to be prepared to access items `0..cellCount-1`.