# How to create CollectionView cells one after another in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

This question has already been answered in Objective-C but I couldn't understand the solution because I don't know Objective-C.

I am in the process of making a demo Wallpaper Browser app and require it to display thumbnails in a collection view for the app's launch screen. 
I managed to get the job done however these images are loaded collectively which would take a long time for (say) 40 images.

How do I set up my view controller such that the thumbnail images are loaded one by one into the collection view rather than collectively?

The following are the Swift files.

**ViewController.Swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


let imageFetcher = ImageFetcher()
var initialItem = 5

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   //imageFetcher.setImageURL()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return initialItem
}

       func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
   // cell.imageView.image = imageFetcher.ImageArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


 }
```

Comment: you need to search for a collection view tutorials.

Comment: Apparently there are none on the subject of "loading Collection View cells one after another". The usual CollectionView tutorials have the simple and usual way of how cells are created loaded etc.

Comment: CollectionViewCells are not created all at once, they are created and configured just before they are displayed, so you aren't loading all the images at once if you are just showing a few of the cells that have images.

Comment: I'd say the issue isn't with your CollectionView code, but with the way you get the images that you are displaying.

Comment: Sir ,there was no Issue with the code. It simply needed some added functionality for sequential cell loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some template code for you. Hope this will be helpful.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var colors = [UIColor]()

    var timer = NSTimer()

    var counter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.colors.append(UIColor.randomColor())

        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: #selector(addCellToCollectionView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        self.timer.invalidate()

    }


    //MARK: - CollectionView Delegate -
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.colors.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, animations: {

            cell.alpha = 1

        })
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.alpha = 0
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        cell.backgroundColor = self.colors[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let width = (collectionView.frame.size.width-20)/3
        let height = width
        let cellSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

        return cellSize
    }



    //MARK: - Timer Selector -
    func addCellToCollectionView(){

        self.counter += 1

        if counter < 30{

            self.colors.append(UIColor.randomColor())
            self.collectionView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0))

        }else{

            self.timer.invalidate()
        }

    }

}



//MARK: - Extensions -

extension CGFloat{

    static func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    }

}

extension UIColor{

    static func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        // If you wanted a random alpha, just create another
        // random number for that too.
        return UIColor(red:   .random(),
                       green: .random(),
                       blue:  .random(),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }

}
```

Don't forget to set **reusable cell identifier** in your .storyboard or .xib file

**UPDATE 3 Aug 15:27** (suggestions for GoldenBanana's answer)

```
var counter = 0

func addCells(timer : NSTimer){

    if(counter == imageFetcher.ImageArray.count){
        timer.invalidate()
        return
    }

    counter = counter + 1

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: counter-1 , inSection: 0)
    collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
}



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("numberOfItemsInSection method just ran")                                                    //timeline indicator
    return counter

}
```

Comment: Can't agree with you, sorry. The idea is that you iteratively add elements to the collectionView data source and reload collectionVew after each iteration. This way the cells appear one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Elena.I'm trying to understand it and get it to work.

Comment: GoldenBanana, welcome! My solution may lacks explanations so ask if you need.

Comment: Yo Elena , I ran a slightly less elaborate version of your code and got it to work. The implementation is incredibly slow however.
Kindly take a look at it and make some suggestions if you have the time.

Comment: The slow performance can be caused by images sizes if they are too large. I tested your code with average size images, seemed totally ok.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get the sequential loading of cells to work using the timer technique as illustrated in Elena's code .

If this is of help to anyone, to answer the question,following things will need to be done

1. Make a *timer*
2. Make a *mutable array*
3. The timer has an action Method(*addCells*) that adds objects from the dataSource array to the mutable array
4. The mutable array dynamically expands itself as time elapses (specified in the timer) and is used to populate the collectionView.

**ViewController.swift**

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

let imageFetcher = ImageFetcher()

var mutableArray : NSMutableArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageFetcher.setImageURL()
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(01, target: self, selector: #selector(addCells), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func addCells(timer : NSTimer){

    var counter = 0
    mutableArray.addObject(imageFetcher.ImageArray[counter])
    counter = counter + 1
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: mutableArray.count-1 , inSection: 0)
    collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
    if(mutableArray.count == imageFetcher.ImageArray.count){
        timer.invalidate()
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("numberOfItemsInSection method just ran")                                                    //timeline indicator
    return mutableArray.count

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
       cell.imageView.image = imageFetcher.ImageArray[indexPath.row]
       return cell
}
}
```

**ImageFetcher.swift**

```
  class ImageFetcher {



var newImage : UIImage?
var ImageArray = [UIImage]()
var imageURL : NSURL?{
    didSet{  newImage = nil
             Adder()
        }
    }

func setImageURL(){
imageURL = DemoURLs.randomImageUrl
}


func fetchImage() {
    if let url = imageURL{
       let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        if imageData != nil{
            self.newImage  = UIImage( data: imageData! )
        } else {
            self.newImage = nil

        }
       }
    }

func Adder(){
    for _ in 1...20 {

        fetchImage()
        ImageArray.append(newImage!)

    }
}
}
```

This answer was previously answered by Mr. rdelmar in the Objective-C language here :
[Loading UICollectionViewCell one at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805659/loading-uicollectionviewcell-one-at-a-time).

Comment: 1. Shouldn't you declare `counter` outside `addCells` function? Otherwise each time `addCells` is called `counter` equals zero again.

Comment: Ok I see. You code works only because you don't really user `counter`. If you use it you don't need `mutableArray` at all.

Comment: I made some changes to your code (*see update to my answer) to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: GoldenBanana, thanks for accepting my answer. Did you manage to fix slow performance?

Comment: I am a novice in iOS , rather programming at large so that will take a while.
But I presume it has something to do with Multithreading. 
I updated my answer with the imageFetcher.swift file for you to have a look at it.